# How to match open and stat mode_t?

Tags: c, unix, posix, file-permissions

I'm creating a file with `open` and setting its permissions, then I get the file permissions using `stat`....the permissions don't match.
The result of the program below is:

> mode from open (600) and stat (100600) are different

**How can I compare the mode(permissions) set by `open(2)` and retrieved with `stat(2)`?**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int
main(int argc, char **argv, char **env) {
        
        const char *path = "/tmp/test";
        const mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR;
        
        if (open(path, O_RDWR |  O_CREAT | O_EXCL, mode) == -1)
                err(1, "open for '%s' failed", path);
        
        struct stat sb;
        if (stat(path, &sb) != 0)
                err(2, "stat failed");
        
        if (mode != sb.st_mode)
                printf("mode from open (%o) and stat (%o) are different\n", 
                        mode, sb.st_mode);

        return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upvoting [user3477950's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314397/how-to-match-open-and-stat-mode-t#24314450) and [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314397/how-to-match-open-and-stat-mode-t#comment37581686_24314450) which lead me to the answer; I'm answering my own question with code.

The key part is `sb.st_mode & RWX_UGO`

So, I ended up with something like:

```
#define RWX_UGO (S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO)
//....
const mode_t file_mode = sb.st_mode & RWX_UGO;
if (mode == file_mode)
        printf("file_mode (%o) & RWX_UGO(%o) equals to(%o) which is "
                    "equal to mode(%o)\n", sb.st_mode, RWX_UGO, 
                    file_mode, file_mode);
else
        printf("mode from open (%o) and stat (%o) are different\n", 
                    mode, file_mode);
```

which now prints

> file_mode (100600) & RWX_UGO(777) equals to(600) which is equal to
>   mode(600)

Answer (score 4):

This is because the `st_mode` member not only contains the access permissions, but a number of other flags as well (e. g. you can check whether the file is a symlink). [Docs here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already read the documentation and yes `st_mode` has more information but...the question is how to compare `st_mode` with t_mode used in `open`. A code example would be very useful

Comment: @user454322 You mask out the noise with `0777`. BTW, not sure why you want to test the modes for equality. It would almost certainly better to test for the individual flags using the provided macros.

Comment: _Although numerically coded permission masks frequently appear in legacy code, you should avoid using numerical values in your programs_ -UNIX Systems Programming by Robbins & Robbins- Is using `0777` safe?

Comment: @user454322 that's right, strictly speaking it's not absolutely portable, although I don't know of a Unix system on which `0777` wouldn't mean `rwx`. For portability reasons, you can replace this with all of the `S_I*` macros bitwise OR'd together.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. I'm using `#define RWX_UGO (S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO)` but still can't get it. Could you provide code?

Comment: @user454322 `#define RWX <all 9 macros bitwise OR'd>`, then `if ((mode & RWX) == (st.st_mode & RWX)) { ... }` etc.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't `#define RWX_UGO (S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO)` equivalen to _all 9 macros_?

Comment: @user454322 oh, I overlooked that. Of course it is.